# Codesandbox thumbnail configuration

Tags: javascript, json, thumbnails, codesandbox

I have some codesandboxes showing the default-sandbox-thumbnail and others showing the thumbnail of the codesandbox right.

See the screenshot of my sandboxes list[image]

It is not clear to me from what is depending

I have looked at the [documentation](https://codesandbox.io/docs/configuration#sandbox-configuration) to understand if i have to configure the `sandbox.config.json` but i have not found anything useful

How can i configure the thumbnail of my codesandboxes?

Comment: This sounds like a [customer-support question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-cant-i-ask-customer-service-related-questions), not a development question. I believe the CodeSandbox previews are auto-generated by taking a screenshot of your app. If the screenshot fails, then you'll just get the default cube png. I don't think there's a way to change this, but you might be able to [open an issue here](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues) asking for that feature.

Comment: There are some open issues but the solution is not clear 1) https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/1563 2) https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/2170

Comment: I see that you added a question to the Github issue, but you should also add links to your sandboxes list so others can look at it and see the problem firsthand. That issue is already closed as well, so it might not get much attention.

Answer (score 3):

This is an existing bug for codesandbox, however i have found a temporary solution for the preview not showing. Take a screenshot of your code/project, rename it **thumbnail.png** and upload in the in the files

[image]

Comment: This solution works 

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in way to create a custom thumbnail, but I've found a workaround.

It's possible to change (update) the thumbnail by visiting https://codesandbox.io/api/v1/sandboxes/SANDBOX_ID/screenshot.png, where `SANDBOX_ID` is the ID of your code sandbox (you can find this by visiting the sandbox you want to customize, then get the last part of the link, e.g. [https://codesandbox.io/s/`h8pG8`](https://codesandbox.io/s/%60h8pG8%60)); codesandbox will visit your sandbox page and take a new sceenshot of your app and update your sandbox.

Here's the hacky part:
Just upload whatever image you want as the thumbnail to your sandbox, then in your homepage just temporarily display that image! You could just do something like:

```html
<img src="/path/to/my/thumbnail" style="position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: cover; z-index: 100;" />
```

Then visit the endpoint (https://codesandbox.io/api/v1/sandboxes/SANDBOX_ID/screenshot.png); check your dashboard to see if the thumbnail changed.

(make sure to delete the image later!)

Comment: I have tried your solution but with no success, Can you please show me how to do it in one of my codesandbox of the list, like this for example https://codesandbox.io/s/circle-threejs-oxdod, so i can accept your answer

Comment: Sorry, it's not the last part of the link; it's the _original_ last part of the link, which in your case is `oxdod`. So visit https://codesandbox.io/api/v1/sandboxes/oxdod/screenshot.png

Comment: The problem is that the screenshot has never been generated for the codesandbox, this is the codesandbox with your hack => https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-cdn-rkq0c, its is not picking up.

Answer (score 1):

Hi: I'm the one who created the GitHub issue [codesandbox/codesandbox-client#2170](https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/issues/2170) that you discovered and [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70597091/codesandbox-thumbnail-configuration#comment124846929_70597091), which addresses this exact topic.

The "screenshot microservice" mentioned in the thread by CodeSandbox employees appears to not be working any longer (or at least not right now). If it did work, you could use a URL in this format to update the screenshot for one of your sandboxes:

```
https://codesandbox.io/api/v1/sandboxes/sandboxId/screenshot.png
```

According to your comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70597091/codesandbox-thumbnail-configuration#comment124859452_70628553), this is the URL you'd use to update the specific sandbox you mentioned:

https://codesandbox.io/api/v1/sandboxes/oxdod/screenshot.png

Because that officially-suggested method isn't working, your most direct route to an answer is to contact customer support using one of the options at the bottom of the CodeSandbox [Frequently Asked Questions](https://codesandbox.io/docs/faq) page. I suggest both sending an email AND opening a new public issue in the repo.

Comment: Thanks, i have opened the issue here => https://github.com/codesandbox/codesandbox-client/discussions/6383, hopefully this can be fixed in a reasonable time, it is a very annoying bug